# Non change able Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT in email Intent

Tags: android

In my app I have a contact via mail function.
However, I have a specific title that I don't want the user to be able to customize / change.

How can this be achieved?

Currrent code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
String title = "My subject";
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
// Other stuff...
```

As it is above, the user can change the title and I don't want this. I want it to be "My subject" in this case.

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. If you're handing off the mailing functionality to an e-mail app, the app will always allow the user to change the subject. If this is critical, you'll have to send the e-mail from inside your app rather than hand it off through an intent.